# Do we need open db whendb is defined in using?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

when I use using for connections, I know there is no need to use close or dispose. I wonder, do we need to use open?

```
using (var dbSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString1"]))
{             
       dbSqlConnection.Open();  // is this required?
}
```

Comment: where else would it be opened?

Comment: no you do not need to do it always its depend on how you going to implement check my answer tooo im not use open() command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing...if you're manually executing a command using the `SqlCommand` object you will definitely need to open the connection before you execute any methods on the command. However, if you're using something like DataAdapter...you don't have to because it will manage the connection for you.

Using the `SqlCommand` object...

```
using (var dbSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString1"]))
{             
       var cmd = new SqlCommand("Your_Sql_Query", con);
       dbSqlConnection.Open();  // is this required?
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

using a `SqlDataAdapter`...

```
using (var dbSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString1"]))
    { 
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, dbSqlConnection );
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
```

Notice that the `SqlDataAdapter` will manage the connection for you, it will open and dispose it

Comment: in second code part, if we use using for adapter too, is it better or no change ?

Comment: it makes not difference...the `SqlDataAdapter` will effectively dispose the connection

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to open it.

The [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) calls the [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method in a `finally` block. It doesn't open any connection. If your code inside in using statement doesn't open your connection on behind (like `SqlDataAdapter`), you need to open it manually.

```
using (var dbSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString1"]))
{             

}
```

is equavalent to

```
var dbSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString1"];
try
{

}
finally
{      
    if (dbSqlConnection != null)
        ((IDisposable)dbSqlConnection).Dispose();
}
```

As you can see, *using statement* doesn't do anything about opening a connection.

Comment: no you do not need to do it always its depend on how you going to implement check my answer tooo im not use open() command

Comment: @LittleDragon Who said _always_? _If your code inside in using statement doesn't open your connection on behind (like SqlDataAdapter), you need to open it manually_

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you are doing. The SqlAdapter for example opens and closes the connection by itself.

If you use the SqlCommand then **yes, you need to open the connection manually to use it** 
because the constructor of `SqlConnection` does not open the connection automatically.

As you said, the `Dispose` method (automatically called when leaving the using block) closes the connection if they is still open.

#### Using

```
using (var dbSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString1"]))
{             
    dbSqlConnection.Open();  // is this required?
}
```

#### Try finally

```
var dbSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString1"];
try
{
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ...", dbSqlConnection);
   dbSqlConnection.Open();
   // execute the SqlCommand e.g. ExecuteReader, ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteScalar 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // handle the exception
}
finally
{   
    // this gets called even if a exception has occured   
    if (dbSqlConnection != null)
       dbSqlConnection.Dispose();
}
```

- [MSDN - SqlConnection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN - SqlDataAdapter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN - SqlCommand Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN - IDisposable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN - using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, just wondering, where is the part of the links you gave that mention it specifically that we need to open it, I only found it by looking at the default enum state is 0 or [Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), a quote would be great

Comment: no you do not need to do it always its depend on how you going to implement check my answer tooo im not use open() command

Comment: @dknaack it is a false statement to say that you HAVE TO open the connection by manually invoking the `Open` method

Comment: @leo I didn't say that the connection needs to open by invoking the open method. I know that there are other ways to do that.

Comment: @dknaack...that's not what I said, what I said was that this statement "Yes, you need to open the connection manually to use it"...as it is, it's false...because the only way to open the connection manually is by invoking `Open` or any of its async counterparts. However, he doesn't need to open it manually, that's why it is false

Answer (score 1):

no you do not need to do it always its depend on how you going to implement im not use open() command

here is the way to do it automatically with  DataAdapter

```
 SqlConnection con = dBClass.SqlConnection(); // return the connection string 

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("[PR_R_TRN_test]", con);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@plong_ID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = ID;


                    DataSet result = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(result);
```

Comment: Is it automatically closed too after calling Fill or do we need to close it using `using` or `Close()`?